# Cordova swift plugin: Use of undeclared type 'CDVPlugin'

Tags: ios, swift, cordova

**Edit:** Nevermind. The answer was: don't import anything because it's exposed globally. I assume this has to do with the bridging header, but it's pretty confusing.

---

I'm trying to write a custom Cordova plugin in Swift, but all of the info I've found has been incomplete or outdated. What is the right way to import `CDVPlugin` in a swift file?

This is what I'm trying:

```
import CDVPlugin
```

But xcode just says `No such module 'CDVPlugin'`. [Cordova's iOS plugin docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/plugin.html) say nothing about using swift.

I have two bridging header files (not sure why) `Bridging-Header.h` and `AppName-Bridging-Header.h`. Under Build Settings, it looks like `AppName-Bridging-Header.h` is the one being used. I've tried adding this to both, but it didn't help:

```
#import <Cordova/CDV.h>
#import <Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>
```

How am I supposed to expose the `CDVPlugin` class to my swift files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to just remove the `import` from my swift file because apparently the bridging header will expose the classes globally.